# Arrayformula that checks if column contains substring including special characters

Tags: google-sheets

Need Arrayformula that checks if column contains substring including special characters. Need to return TRUE if Input 2 contains the string in Input 1. Not case sensitive. And consider special characters. Here is a [link to sample sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c9vBShVK_iyxOelo1Dc0THVRJtP3U0pmiPcxbrLLSJ0/edit#gid=221183113)

[image]

I attempted in another sheet with:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"Contains Filter View"; IF(REGEXMATCH($F$6:$F,$F$4),TRUE,"")})`

But it doesn't consider special characters like perenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=vstack("Header",
        map(C5:C,D5:D,lambda(c,d,ifs((c="")*(d=""),,c="",false,iferror(search(c,d)),true,1,false))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using value in cell for building a regex pattern will be hard and error prone.

See below a function using native gsheet formula :

`=IFERROR(IF(ISEMPTY(C5),false,SEARCH(C5,D5)>=1),false)`

(I translated formula from my native tongue set up : `=SIERREUR(SI(ESTVIDE(C5),false,CHERCHE(C5,D5)>=1),true)`)

[image]

---

PS: Answer from rockinfreakshow is working great and closer to your requirement ! But please note that it's harder to debug if someone need to fix it